# Formik field has error after resetForm() in reactNative

Tags: react-native, formik

I have the following `onSubmit` handler for my form:

```
try {
        const data = await api.post('/auth/signup', {
          ...values,
        });

        navigation.navigate(ROUTES.EMAILCONFIRMATION);
        resetForm();

        return data;
      } catch (e) {
        // If there's an error, set the status of the form to that error and display it below
        setStatus(e.response?.data.message);
      }
```

You can see that after i post to the API, I navigate away from the current screen, and then i reset the form, however, when I go back to the form there will be an error on the last field I touched, let's say i've put my email in and then the password, i submit, navigate and reset and then the error will appear because it will think i 'touched' the field i typed in and therefore it'll be taken as `touched` hence throwing an error

This is how i display error messages:

```
    {touched.password && errors.password && (
      <FormErrorMessage error={errors.password} />
    )}
```

Comment: can you call the resetForm() function with your initialValues? So it will be resetForm(initialValues)